# How to install TeXLive 2020 on Linux Mint?

Tags: texlive

I have downloaded install-tl-unx.tar.gz
and run

```
sudo ./install-tl
sudo apt-get purge texlive-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After compiling a .tex file, there is still TeX Live 2017/Debian in .log file.

Comment: You need to add the directory of your new installation to your `PATH`, `MANPATH`, and `INFOPATH`, in *front* of the system paths, in your `.profile`.

Comment: The advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) should work for you. (I think it’s worth scrolling down to my answer, but I’m biased.)

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what to do. I followed the procedure in the link and where should I add that commands, please?

Comment: There are a couple of possible places, but one of the simplest is to save the commands to a file in `/etc/profile.d/`. For example `/etc/profile.d/texlive.sh`. You can see cfr’s answer to the question for another version.

Comment: I cannot add the file with commands to /etc/profile.d

Comment: note that if you get texlive from tug that is completely separate from the packages managed by apt, so typically you leave the system tex in place and just put the texlive 2020 bin directory at the front of your PATH

Comment: @ElenaGreg That’s a system directory, so you would need to create and edit the file as root.

Comment: Thank you and then, should I ran texlive.sh? It did not suceed.